# export csv file with password protection in php codeigniter

Tags: passwords

I need to export a csv file with password protection from tabletools in php codeigniter. Unable to set password in csv file. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a 'featureless' flat file format and you will not be able to set a password.

Perhaps export the CSV into a password protected zip file.

Comment: After export the csv file i need to send a mail to a person, he update some data in that password protected csv file he need to re mail to us, and i need to upload that csv file, thats why i need that security.

Comment: To be clear, it is NOT possible to password protect a CSV.

Comment: xslx file is not csv, they are completely different file formats. However, I do believe you can password protect excel files programmatically.